# Integrate Wave Dashboards with Visual Force page, to view it on Salesforce 1 mobile app?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, dashboard, analytics, einstein-analytics

Particularly want to use the Salesforce 1 mobile app, and not the Wave Analytics Mobile app.

**Here's my code:**

[image]

Comment: That is not possible and we are also facing the same issue. We Embedded the Dashboard in a VF so that we can prepopulate the filters, but the VF does not render properly in Salesforce1. Please share the answer if you come to know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your VF page is already working and rendering the Wave Dashboard data, it's actually fairly simple to enable the Visualforce page in Salesforce1

You just need to enable the `Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages` for your VF page.

This would then be available as a Salesforce1 left sidebar menu option. You can customise the Salesforce1 left menu by moving items up/down as explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizing_navigation_pane.htm&language=en_US).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! However, I am not able to scroll vertically or horizontally in the Salesforce1 app. Are there any ways where salesforce1 app allows us to use the codes that have been specified like this:

`"layouts": [
            {
                "device": "default",
                "pages": [
                    {
                        "rows": [
                            "row:{height=40}",
                            "header_1 {colspan=2}",
                            "link_1 | link_2",
                            "row:{height=40}",
`

Answer (score 0):

Use lightning builder.. It has a Wave Dashboard Component - you can then add this onto SF1

Works really well :)